# for loop does not iteration in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.1 for my project.
My issue was to dispaly the data as per category_id which foreign key of table category.
This code only get DATA having category_id 1 and this loop only run at $i=1 and after that they can not be iterate.
Please help me to solve out this issue.

My controller code was:-

```
public function category()
{
 $category2=Category::all();

    for($i=1;$i<=count($category2);$i++)
    {
    $category=HelpCenter::where('category_id','=',$i)->get();

    return view('folder/category',compact('category'));

    }
```

}

My view code was:-

```
   @foreach($category as $category)

    <li><a href="/category/{{$category->id}}"> {{$category->questions}}</a></li>

    @endforeach
```

Comment: dd(count($category2)); see what it prints... also returning a view in a for loop? What actually you want to achieve? The return statement terminates the execution of a function and returns control to the calling function. Execution resumes in the calling function at the point immediately following the call. A return statement can also return a value to the calling function. https://www.google.com/search?q=php+return+statement&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=what+does+return+statement+do

Comment: What's the relationship between categories and helpcenter?

Comment: `$category = Category::join('help_center_table','help_center_table.category_id','=','category_table.id')->get();` You can add select() to specify columns

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same variable for iterating as the array you are iterating (`$category as $category`). You MUST be getting some kind of error because of that.

That being said, you cannot return multiple views with a controller. You will just return the first result that you get.

What you should be doing is something like this:

```
public function category()
{
    $category2=Category::all();
    $categories = [];
    for($i=1;$i<=count($category2);$i++)
    {
        $categories[]=HelpCenter::where('category_id','=',$i)->get();
    }
    return view('folder/category',compact('categories'));
}
```

And then in your view:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)

    <li><a href="/category/{{$category->id}}"> {{$category->questions}}</a></li>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be change in your example except that you are passing an array variable...

Comment: Sorry, moved out the view out of the loop so you actually get the full categories instead of whatever the first loop iteration returns. Also you should notice that I have changed the variable names in the view.

Comment: this code shows error in view file Undefined property: $id

Comment: Well, I can't really know what's in your HelpCenter object. Does it not have an id column?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from the loop when it runs for one category. Just place your return line after closing loop braces. Like this..

```
    public function category()
    {
      $category2=Category::all();
      for($i=1;$i<=count($category2);$i++)
      {
        $category[]=HelpCenter::where('category_id','=',$i)->get();
      }
      return view('folder/category',compact('category'));
    }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: In your example $category will pass a single object rather a collection of objects. It will override the values and will pass the last collection object.

Comment: I have updated this answer. I think now it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to use relationship between `Category` and `HelpCenter` . For more info [Check Here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

But if you want to do this way then I think this is better way :

```
public function category()
{
   $category2=Category::all();
   $category = [];
   foreach($category2 as $cat ){ 
        $category[] = HelpCenter::where('category_id','=',$cat->id)->get();
   } 
    return view('folder/category',compact('category'));

}
```